# Search in multiple components inside whole application from single Nav bar header in react with hooks

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

In my application, I have a common navbar that has a search box.
I need to apply the search to any of the components in my whole application.
I am using hooks/custom hooks. The main problem I am facing is that I am not able to trigger the state from the Search component to any of the components with custom hooks.

What can be the best approach to implement in which I can filter data with a single search box?

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple components depending on a component for search. The ideal way to pass the data around would be using global state management.

For this, you can use React context or Redux for example.

https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/useContext